# Git hook to upload file to different directory

Tags: git

First of all, I'm a Git newbie. I just copied post-receive hook from a blog article.

I have a remote git repo that has this structure:

```
app/
public/
```

And my website is structured like this:

```
app/
html/
```

The `public` and `html` have the same content, they just have different names because my server can't use the `public` name.

I have this post-receive hook so that when I make a push, the website files will be updated:

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/path/to/my/website/ git checkout -f
```

Now, since my git repo and website structure are different, is there a hook I can make that when I make a push the the repo's `public` directory, the file will be updated in the website's `html` directory?

Comment: @janos because in my server, "html" is the recognized folder for http and in my local, it's "public". The tiny little script doesn't look harmful. I'm a web developer and I think I can tell if it's harmful or not.

Comment: I see, I completely misunderstood your question. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think symbolic links can help you here. That is, you can either create a symlink on your server to point from `html` to `public`, or in your local environment to point from `public` to `html`, so that the same hook script can work in both environments.